# How should i organize typescript modules/packages using tsd typings?

Tags: node.js, typescript, definitelytyped

I've got quite a large TS-project with numbers of internal libraries that are linked to each other as npm packades.
Sometimes in .ts i need to put a references to some ambient or external definitions, provided by TSD, like this:
`/// <reference path="../../typings/tsd.d.ts" />`
Each package includes own .d.ts files referencing to `...root.../typings/tsd.d.ts`.

So, when i install a dependency package inside of another one, there can be a multiple definition for some ambient stuff, such as `...root.../typings/node/node.d.t`. And it causes transpiling errors `Duplicate identifier`.

I think you all know that problem. But i've spent about a day googling and reading and trying numbers of solutions that didn't work fine. :(

Please, show me a way out of this. Tell me how you do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... A weird idea has come. 
Put in all projects a `postinstall` hook script that changes the `typings/tsd.d.ts` and replaces paths of duplicating definition files to the parent poject's ones, something like this: `/// <reference path="../../../../typings/node/node.d.ts" />`

It's dirty but could work fine

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');



function searchParentTypingPath(currentPath, moduleName, depth){
    if (!depth) depth = 1;
    if (depth>4) return null;
    try{
        var filePath = currentPath+'/typings/'+moduleName+'/'+moduleName+'.d.ts';
        fs.accessSync(filePath);
        return filePath;
    }
    catch(e){
        return searchParentTypingPath(currentPath+'/..', moduleName, depth+1);
    }
}


module.exports = function (tsdFilePath, verbose){
    var tsdContent = fs.readFileSync(tsdFilePath).toString();
    var resultContent = '';
    tsdContent.split('\n').forEach(function(line){
        var match = line.match(/^\/\/\/\s+<reference path="([\/a-zA-Z0-9_\-.]+)"\s*\/>/);
        if (!match) {
            resultContent+=line+'\n';
            return;
        }
        var modulePath = match[1];
        if (!modulePath.match(/^\w+/)) {// it's not provided by TSD
            resultContent+=line+'\n';
            return;
        }
        var moduleName =  path.basename(modulePath, '.d.ts');

        var parentPath = searchParentTypingPath(path.dirname(tsdFilePath)+'/../..', moduleName);
        resultContent+='/// <reference path="'+(parentPath||modulePath)+'" />\n';
    });
    if (verbose) {
        console.log(resultContent);
        return resultContent;
    }
    fs.writeFileSync(tsdFilePath, resultContent);
};
```